# How to fix this antlr grammar , multiple nodes

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, grammar

all, here is the gramma:

**columnName (',' columnName)* -> ^(SM_TOK columnName)**

I want the output ast of "**A,B**" to have multiple **SM_TOK** nodes , like : **(SM_TOK A) (SM_TOK B)**

But,currently,I only have: **(SM_TOK A)**

It seems that 'B' will be ignored.

Can anyone help me to fix this gramma?

Thanks!

Comment: Since you got answered here, could you then post the answer (or a link to this Q&A) to the ANTLR mailing-list where you posted the same question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your left side specifies one or more `columnName` items, but the right side mentions only one. Try adding a `+`, like this:

```
columnName (',' columnName)* -> ^((SM_TOK columnName)+)
```